# Environment variables that one should update when using a new compiler

Tags: gcc, environment-variables

Say a system admin provides a new version of the gcc compiler available on `/some/path` on a machine where I build software (all types of software including open source, 3rd party tools, my own programs, etc.):

I usually update the following three environment variables `$PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$MANPATH`,  according to what I understand is standard practice for interfacing with general building tools (e.g. `autoconf`, `cmake`, etc.) or scripts.

```
setenv MY_GCC /some/path

setenv PATH $MY_GCC/bin:$PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $MY_GCC/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv MANPATH $MY_GCC/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Here I have a quick question: is there really a reason to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (why would programs link against a compiler?).

But more generally, **what environment variables should one update upon the installation of a new compiler to guarantee a proper building environment**?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Generally, you do not need to set up any environment variables other than `PATH` to have a proper building environment (and if you use an IDE, not even that may be necessary, though you might have to tell the IDE where to find the compiler if it lives in an unexpected, non-standard location).

If you use something like `autoconf` (or CMAKE, or any similar thing), and especially if you have several compiler versions (or cross compilers) on the system, you may want to set variables like `CC` or `CXX` to a reasonable default just to be sure (and modify them accordingly if you want something else).
Though if your compiler has its target appended to its name (as in most builds), this is probably not necessary. At least, it works perfectly well for me without doing anything special.

If English is not your native language and your GCC was built with locale support (most stupid idea ever, if you ask me), you may want to set `LC_ALL` to "C". Otherwise you'll notice that your "unreadable" error messages won't get you much help if you ask for a compiler problem on a forum.

If you have a ramdisk (or SSD) in addition to a normal harddisk, but your projects are on the normal harddisk, you may want to set `TMPDIR` (even if you always compile with `-pipe`, since this sometimes seems to create temp files anyway for a reason I don't understand).

If you have non-standard locations for libraries that you want to use, you *can* set `LIBRARY_PATH`, but I advise against it. It is better to have your build scripts (or project settings in the IDE) such that these locations are given to the linker on the commandline (or passed through `configure` with something like `--with-foo-path=...`). This guarantees that your projects build *everywhere and anywhere* without requiring someone else to performa a magic dance with some unknown, obscure environment variables. The same goes for `C_INCLUDE_PATH`.